# custom `smooth()` method for a custom class

Tags: r

I'm wondering why a custom `smooth()` function for a custom class is not taking precedence over `stats::smooth()`. Here is an example:

```
create_my_class = function(mydata){
  class(mydata) = c("my_class", "data.frame")
  return(mydata)
}

df = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
df = create_my_class(df)
```

Now, I know I can define a `plot()` function for this class, and it will supersede other `plot()` methods when I pass a `myclass` object:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot.my_class = function(data){
  ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point()
}

plot(df)
```

[image]

But why doesn't this approach work with a function called `smooth.my_class()`? For instance, this simple smoothing function:

```
smooth.my_class = function(data){
  lm(y~x, data)
}
```

when run as `smooth(df)` throws the error "Error in smooth(df) : attempt to smooth non-numeric values", which is the same if I run `stats::smooth(df)`.

Is there a bigger problem here? Can only certain function names be re-used to take a custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a bigger problem here. If you want to define a specific method to handle a particular class, the function in question needs to be a *generic* function.

For example, look at the function definition for `print`:

```r
print
#> function (x, ...) 
#> UseMethod("print")
```

That's all there is to the function `print`. When you type `print(object)` into the console, this function executes, and all it does is look up the class of `object`, append the class name to the word `print` and look up *that* function. For example, if `object` is of class "data.frame", then `UseMethod("print")` looks for `print.data.frame`, and if it exists, will call it with the arguments you supplied to `print`. If no specific method exists for a class, a generic function has (or should have)  a fallback default method.

The reason why your custom `smooth` function doesn't work is that `smooth` is **not** a generic function. When you run `smooth`, no lookup of a class-specific method occurs, and you just get plain old `stats::smooth`

You *could* make `smooth` a generic function though. The following should dispatch correctly for your custom class and in all other cases default to `stats::smooth`:

```r
smooth <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("smooth")

smooth.my_class = function(data, ...){
  lm(y~x, data)
}

smooth.default <- function(x, ...) stats::smooth(x, ...)
```

For example if we try it on your custom class we get an `lm`

```r
smooth(df)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            x  
#>     0.07497      0.09133
```

But calling it on a numeric vector invokes `stats::smooth`

```
smooth(df$x)
#> 3RS3R Tukey smoother resulting from  stats::smooth(x = x) 
#>  used 6 iterations
#>   [1]  0.08976935  0.08976935  0.08976935 -0.19641797 -0.19641797 -0.19641797
#>   [7] -0.19641797  0.02547707  0.08861531  0.08861531 -0.03327923 -0.09422650
#>  [13] -0.09422650 -0.15654766 -0.15654766 -0.37095531 -0.49807061 -0.87394069
#>  [19] -1.18237852 -1.18237852 -0.05479660 -0.05479660 -0.05479660  0.26811991
#>  [25]  0.37611915  0.37611915  0.70314430  0.70314430  0.70314430  0.70314430
#>  [31]  0.70314430  0.24278460  0.24278460  0.24278460  0.51725720  0.51725720
#>  [37]  0.51725720  0.51725720  0.67223056  0.67223056  0.67223056  0.67223056
#>  [43]  0.67223056  0.09257700  0.08426558  0.08426558  0.08426558  0.08426558
#>  [49]  0.08426558  0.51762272  0.51762272  0.51762272  0.51762272  0.51762272
#>  [55]  0.51762272  0.02758035  0.02758035  0.10725655  0.13239083  0.13239083
#>  [61]  0.18802296  0.18802296  0.55088073  0.55088073  0.55088073  0.55088073
#>  [67]  0.55088073  0.76919007  0.76919007  0.76919007  0.48469683  0.48469683
#>  [73] -0.32896249 -0.32896249 -0.31640679 -0.28686752 -0.21660688 -0.21660688
#>  [79] -0.21660688 -0.21660688 -0.87848779 -0.87848779 -0.87848779 -1.69139208
#>  [85] -1.77982364 -1.77982364 -1.22898324  0.33751308  0.44113212  0.44113212
#>  [91]  0.85571511  0.85571511  0.85571511  0.34594270  0.29631435  0.19705764
#>  [97] -0.02076665 -0.02076665 -0.02076665 -0.02076665
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Awesome, thank you. "You _could_ make a `smooth` generic function..." I sense from your note it is a bad idea. Is it? (Context is that I am developing a package.)

Comment: @invictus In general I would try to avoid creating a function with the same name as a function in one of the base packages, though there are certainly precedents for this (`dplyr` does it with `filter` for example). I can't _think_ of any obvious problems creating a new S3 generic called `smooth` would cause, as long as you use `stats::smooth` as the default method.